# How to display specific background images in each different index.html in 1 folder

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a folder in which there are several index.html files, how do I make it so that each index.html displays a different background?

for example index1.html displays background 1.png, index2.html displays background 2.png, and so on.

all of these index.html depend on the same images and css folder, all of the images have been added to the images file

```html
    <section class="u-align-center u-clearfix u-image u-shading u-section-1" src="images/banner.png" id="sec-597c">
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
        <h1 class="u-text u-title u-text-1">tiket</h1>
```

```
.u-section-1 {background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), url("images"); background-position: 50% 50%}
.u-section-1 .u-sheet-1 {min-height: 634px}
.u-section-1 .u-text-1 {font-weight: 700; font-size: 3.75rem; margin: 142px 484px 0 39px}
.u-section-1 .u-text-2 {margin: 22px 374px 0 52px}
.u-section-1 .u-btn-1 {background-image: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700; border-style: none; font-size: 1.5rem; animation-duration: 1000ms; box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 0 rgba(128,128,128,1); margin: 22px auto 60px 262px; padding: 12px 15px 13px}
```

Comment: Hello , welcome to stackoverflow , add your html & CSS , show us what you did

Comment: Please add your code in a snippet. Check button `<>` in markdown editor

Comment: add it to your post  m8

Comment: sorry its my first time make a post and comment in stackoverflow

Comment: In my opinion the organized way is to create a CSS file to each HTML file and add background to their bodys, thats way each HTML has it's own CSS and it's own background

Answer (score 0):

You can create and add specific class for each of your pages.

.page1 .u-section-1 {background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), url("images"); background-position: 50% 50%}

.page2 .u-section-1 {background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.55), rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), url("images2"); background-position: 50% 50%}